# Moment.js and Angular library

Tags: angular, momentjs, libraries, angular-library

I am using Moment.js in my custom angular library. I used to import it in library like that:
`import * as moment_ from 'moment'; const moment = moment_;`
I have local playground where I build it and check for errors. Everything works. But after uploading it to NPM and upgrading to version with moment.js in my main project - I got this type error:
[image: type error]

Library config:
Angular version: 13.3.10
Moment.js: 2.29.3

Project config:
Angular version: 13.5.0
Moment.js: 2.29.3

I have tried import it in different ways (e.g. import * as moment from 'moment') and rebuild it multiple times and no luck.
Any guesses what causes the error?

Comment: Do you share Moment.js date objects between your app and your library?

Comment: @rveerd Not really understand what you mean. What do you mean under date objects?

Comment: A date or time object that you create with the `moment()` constructor.

Comment: Is Moment.js a _dependency_ or a _peer dependency_ of the library?

Comment: 1. I don’t share moment.js date objects between my app and library. 
2. Moment.js goes as a peer dependency of the library. 
But at the same time I use moment.js in my app.

Comment: If Moment.js really is an internal dependency of the library it might be better to declare it as a dependency of the library instead of a peer dependency.

Comment: @rveerd I`ve tried and no luck :( 
Error is still there. I think version difference of moment.js between my main app and library causes the error. I am currently trying to find a workaround with versions but still no luck.

Comment: Moment,js is no longer maintained. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) is a modern, alternative library with a similar API. Perhaps you can use that instead.

Comment: Thats actually a valid point. I wish I could :D The reason is that on my project moment.js is used and I won`t be allowed to move to Luxon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that you should check out for other packages that use moment.js in your main app and after this change version of moment.js in your library or update those on your main project.

E.g. In my main app was package that uses moment.js v2.18.1 and this isn't supporting some methods available in v2.29.3. So I migrated to newer option and problem was solved.

P.S. -> As [@rveerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6783775/rveerd) said - Moment,js is no longer maintained. You should use some other library instead. Luxon for example(which was developed by moment.js developers BTW).